# excel cells protection

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have made an application. All i want is that only i have permission to edit the cells or rows. rest employees can edit only those cells which i allow them to. is it possible? also i would like to place this document on a shared drive. n i want that no 2 users can make changes in it at same time. i.e. if one user s using it, n other triest o open it, he gets an alert that this user is using it. would you like to notify?

Is there any way out for both of my problems? i tried going to tools> allow users to edit range > added a range > permission > add > "entered the email ids" apply and clied on denied without password for this range and applied. but it dint work.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/allow_specific_users_to_edit_ranges_in_a_protected_worksheet.html for instance. If it isn't enough, please edit your question to be clearer in your expecations

Answer (score 1):

Yes

Go to Tools (or the Review tab if < 2007)

- Protection  (if < 2007)
- Protect Sheet

You should have enough options in the new window which pops up.

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lock-cells-in-a-worksheet-HA010342979.aspx
- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=450384

Comment: Protecting the sheet locks the whole sheet for me also